# Undefined reference, trying to create vector like struct

Tags: c++, struct

I tried to create something vector-like myself, so I tried to create a struct for that. I constantly get "undefined reference to 'float_vector::val' " which I cannot resolve.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct float_vector
{
    static float val[50];
    int i =0;

    float* pointer()
    {
        return val;
    }
    void push_back2(float value)
    {
        val[i] = value;
        i++;
    }
    int size2()
    {
        return i;
    }
    float at2(int ati)
    {
        return val[ati];
    }
};
int main()
{
    float_vector aa, some, tmep;
    some.push_back2(5);
    some.push_back2(5.5);
    some.push_back2(5.779);
    cout << (some.pointer())[1];
    cout << some.size2();

  int u, p;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `static float val[50];` Why `static`? Just `float val[50];` will be fine.

Comment: "I tried to create something vector-like myself" - Why? Why not just use `std::vector`? You are *very* unlikely to do better and *very* likely to do *significantly worse*.

Comment: just use the std::vector or look at its implementation.
remove the 'static'

Comment: And what textbook are you learning this stuff from?

Comment: Yes it worked. Why does it work???
I did not want to create something better then std::vector I just wanted something conveniant that would work on arduino

Comment: (I suspect the arduino compiler is not yet up to this) In C++, the data attribute "static float val[50];" is shared by any instance of "struct float_vector".  Thus, add to your testing the same cout for each instance:  aa, some, and temp;  to convince yourself that your declaration serves your needs.

Answer (score -2):

Because of the downvotes i will elaborate on answer. Statics are defined outside of class scope, so to just compile it, add below line to introduce your static to your compiler symbol table:

```
float float_vector::val[50];
```

As other people pointed out this is poor design, and you should not write your sudo vector container this way. Val will be shared by all instance of your class, so data will be overriden and you will have no way of keeping size and capacity. Also size is fixed so this has not much to do what vector offers. Thats being said, you should use dynamic memory for underlying storage, preferably using RAII, to check good example implementation check "The C++ programming language" c++11 edition, page 375, there is proper example of vector implementation.

Comment: This will fix the problem, strictly speaking. But it will be a very poor vector implementation if every instance shares an underlying array. I believe that explains the downvotes.

Comment: That's actually a definition. But  I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: Also, " add below your class definition" is wrong - it should be in a separate C++ source file.